# SQL if/else update table based on value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to figure out how to do a complex update in SQL that affects two tables.

My 2 tables look like:

```
  t1: key, val_1 (with key as the primary key)
  t2: t1_key, user_id, val_2 (with t1_key and user_id as the primary key)
```

What I need figure out is how to do an update which says, given a user_id "u" and a key "k":

```
  if  (["u"+"k"] does not exist at all in t2) {
    update t1.val = t1.val+1 where key="k";
    insert ("u","k",1) into t2;
  } else if ( ["u"+"k"] exists in t2 and val_2 < 1 ) {
    update t1.val = t1.val+1 where key="k";
    update t2.val2 = t2.val2+1 where t1_key="k" AND user_id="u";
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your pseudo code looks exactly like a query. I typed it out on SQL Fiddle for you:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19597d/11

```
declare @k int = 3
declare @user_id int = 1

if not exists (select * from t2
               where user_id = @user_id
               and t1_k = @k) begin
  update t1 set val = val + 1 where k = @k
  insert t2 values (@k, @user_id, 1) 
end else if
  exists ( select * from t2 
          where user_id = @user_id
          and t1_k = @k
          and val < 1) begin
  update t1 set val = val + 1 where k = @k
  update t2 set val = val + 1 
    where t1_k = @k 
    and user_id = @user_id
end

select * from t1;
select * from t2;
```

When you go implement this, though, you'll want transactions. (Fiddle didn't seem to like that.)

Not sure if you mean for some cases to not do anything, but your code doesn't have a final else clause.

Comment: Perfect!  I think the BEGIN-END was the piece I was missing.  Thank you!